# Show mp3 artwork in picturebox C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a music player and when playing music I want to show the artwork of the current mp3 in a picture box.
I have surfed the internet but couldn't find a solution.
So please help.

**EDIT:** I want to get the artwork from the ID3 tags.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is too generic. Do you want to get the cover from an ID3 tag, or from a file next to the mp3 file or from the internet using a third party service etc etc. We can't help with such a vague request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily with [taglib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/).

I created a simple application showing this. Application contains the following:

- A `PictureBox` called `coverPictureBox`.
- A `Button` called `browseButton`.
- An `OpenFileDialog` called `openFileDialog`.

In my main form's constructor I set the `openFileDialog`'s default extension to mp3 and prevent multiple file selection:

```
openFileDialog.DefaultExt = "mp3";
openFileDialog.Filter = "MP3 Files (*.mp3)|*.mp3";
openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
```

In the button's `Click` event handler:

```
private void coverButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(openFileDialog.FileName);
        var mStream = new MemoryStream();
        var firstPicture = file.Tag.Pictures.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstPicture != null)
        {
            byte[] pData = firstPicture.Data.Data;
            mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
            var bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);
            mStream.Dispose();
            coverPictureBox.Image = bm;
        }
        else
        {
            // set "no cover" image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the answer I have been looking for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TagLib for that purpose. https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp

This Question contains an answer that shows how to display the picture from the MP3 file in a Windows Forms picture box: [C# mp3 ID tags with taglib - album art](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247216/c-sharp-mp3-id-tags-with-taglib-album-art)

This contains the correct approach when using WPF: [Using taglib to display the cover art in a Image box in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904184/using-taglib-to-display-the-cover-art-in-a-image-box-in-wpf)