# Album art of mp3 music file

Tags: c#, uwp

How I can get album art from mp3 file in Universal Windows App?

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

please also read [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). also: have you tried typing `c# get mp3 album cover` in a search engine? this question has already been asked - and answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show mp3 artwork in picturebox C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103287/show-mp3-artwork-in-picturebox-c-sharp)

Comment: No my question not about Win32 apps.

Comment: How do this in UWP?

Comment: it's about getting the image out of the mp3-file. and you _really_ should be able to research how to show an image in an UWP-app. using search engines is a key skill for every good developer - and you _could_ show a little effort of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getthumbnailasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_GetThumbnailAsync_Windows_Storage_FileProperties_ThumbnailMode_System_UInt32_) method to do this. If you want to get more info, please refer to the Scenario2 of [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/filethumbnails/).

XAML code:

```
<Grid>        
    <StackPanel>
         <Button Content="Load Album art" Click="Button_Click"/>
         <Image x:Name="ImageControl"/>
      </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
            StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                const ThumbnailMode thumbnailMode = ThumbnailMode.MusicView;
                const uint size = 100;
                using (StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(thumbnailMode, size))
                {
                    if (thumbnail != null && thumbnail.Type == ThumbnailType.Image)
                    {
                        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                        bitmapImage.SetSource(thumbnail);
                        ImageControl.Source = bitmapImage;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please do not answer zero-effort obvious duplicates. Instead find an existing Q&A that answer this question.